# Setting up Pylint with PyDev

Tags: pydev, pylint, eclipse-3.5

I have installed pylint via easy_install. I can run `pylint <filename>` with success. But pydev refuses to use it.

- I checked "use pylint"
- I configured correct path
- I updated my python interpreter in eclipse to have pylit in pythonpath
- I use Eclipse Galileo
- I have build automatically checked
- I tried cleaning whole project and no errors

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Having a similar problem now trying to get eclipse+pydev(w/pylint: astng0.20.0, common0.49.0, pylint0.18.0) on a new machine.  But I get the following error:

AttributeError: 'ASTNGManager' object has no attribute 'set_cache_size'

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding the project was enough for me. (I had already added the source folder to PyDev-PYTHONPATH.)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'm guessing you may need to mark the folder that contains your code as a *source folder*. You can do this under project properties.

- Project->Properties->PyDev-PYTHONPATH
- add relevant folders to the list of sources.

Comment: If it's helpful, this config is stored in .pydevproject. In my case, an auto-script was editing that file, breaking pylint.

Comment: I have configured this though I had the same issue and I resolved by following this step:  Pylint should run whenever the source is changed and built, but you can go to the menu Project -> Clean... to force the python script to be built and code checked by Pylint;     Reference Source: http://goo.gl/SYg1yj

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed that Pydev won't run Pylint on files with dashes (hyphens) the the filename; according to the Pydev devs, '-' is not a valid Python module name character, and it doesn't look like they intend to fix it:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1915426&group_id=85796&atid=577329

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2888890&group_id=85796&atid=577332

As if nobody writes scripts in Python...  Grumble grumble...

Answer (score 0):

To provide an alternative solution, `pylint` can be used as an **`External Tool`** in Eclipse. This requires having previously installed the `pylint` package for a Python installation.

Remember to first have a `pylintrc` file somewhere where pylint can find it, failing which a "`No config file found`" error is printed. Typically I would `touch pylintrc` inside the project directory, and keep the file in version control. For reference, see [pylint command-line options](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/run.html#command-line-options).

In Eclipse, select `Run`, `External Tools`, `External Tools Configurations...`. Click the toolbar button to create a `New launch configuration`. Configure as below or as desired:

- Name: `pylint`
- Location: `${system_path:pylint}`
- Working Directory: `${project_loc}`
- Arguments: `--reports=n "${resource_loc}"`

Remember to click inside an open file to switch focus to it before running the above external tool for it. Failing this, an error can occur.

The output of the external tool will by default be printed to the console.

---

Related: [Setting up pep8 as an External Tool in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2296249/832230)