# How can I configure Pylint to check all things PEP8 checks?

Tags: python, coding-style, lint, pylint, pep8

[Searching](http://search.gmane.org/?query=pep8&group=gmane.comp.python.logilab) for an answer on Pylint's mailing list brings no interesting results.

Pylint is known to be very customizable, so I guess this should be possible...

The reason I would like Pylint to check compliance with PEP8 is because

- PyDev has much better [support](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_pylint.html) for Pylint than it has for PEP8.
- It's easier to have one tool doing all checks than having to use two.

I also asked this question on Pylint's mailing list at http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.logilab/1039

Example of diagnostic messages from PEP8 which I don't get from Pylint:

- E203 whitespace before ':'
- E225 missing whitespace around operator
- E251 no spaces around keyword / parameter equals
- E301 expected 1 blank line, found 0
- E303 too many blank lines
- E501 line too long (90 characters)
- W291 trailing whitespace
- W292 no newline at end of file
- W293 blank line contains whitespace

Comment: The link is broken (with a truly exotic error message:  *"Error 523. Ray ID: 6115420619df7383 • 2021-01-14 06:21:37 UTC. Origin is unreachable"*).

Answer (score 12):

- E203 is not yet supported in Pylint AFAIK
- E225 is C0322 / C0323
- E251 should be C0322/C0323, but I'm not sure that Pylint does not special case parameters and allows lack of space there
- E301, E303 are not supported AFAIK
- E501 is C0301 and you can configure the length in your `pylintrc`
- W291, W292 and W203 are not supported AFAIK.

It would be nice if you could report these as desired features [over here](https://www.logilab.org/project/pylint).

Comment: Regarding C0322/3, in version 0.25.1, PyLint does have a 'special case' that allows there to be no spaces before/after the assignment operator for default and keyword arguments, but it doesn't complain if there *is* a space either side of the operator, which it probably should to be strictly PEP 8-compliant.

Comment: Alex, are there any plans to support all PEP8 features? I'm asking as there was no activity in ticket #82519 since it was created almost a year ago...

Comment: The official position is to use `pycodestyle` (former `pep8` tool) for that. See https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1970