# Eclipse plugin that enforce code documentation

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, code-documentation

I'm developing python with PyDev in eclipse.
I'm looking for a plugin that will help me enforce documentation on my code.

Does anyone knows of such a plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly for Eclipse, but you could tie pep8 (the PEP-8 validator) to every git commit. One of the things pep8 complains is lack of docstrings.

Never tried, but http://widerin.org/blog/using-pep8-checks-in-eclipse should help you.

edit: as alko pointed out, it's integrated with PyDev. There is another discussion on "[How to configure PyLint to check all things PEP8 checks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879640/how-to-configure-pylint-to-check-all-things-pep8-checks)"

Comment: this is now standard feature for PyDev (starting from 2.3.0): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399956/how-to-integrate-pep8-py-in-eclipse