# Make Pylint care about blank lines

Tags: python, pylint, pep8, pylintrc

I am not a stickler for most things pep-8, but certain things I personally prefer when writing code (as opposed to for work, where I would adhere to the style or lack thereof of the existing code base).

One thing I personally tend to follow is pep-8's suggestion about [blank lines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines):

> Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank
>   lines.
>
> Method definitions inside a class are surrounded by a single blank
>   line.

However, I have not been able to get Pylint to warn me when I violate this. I don't see anything that seems relevant disabled in my `.pylintrc`, and I have not been able to figure out if this is possible in Pylint, and if so, how to enable it.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7441902/3642398), it looks like there are certain aspects of pep-8 that Pylint does not (or did not at the time) cover, but I have not been able to ascertain whether this is the case for blank lines.

**Is it possible to have Pylint warn about blank lines (too many/not enough) without writing custom extensions?**

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I searched for "line" in what I think is the best documentation of pylint's features, and I didn't find anything: https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference_guide/features.html?highlight=line

Comment: @Evan haha, yeah. That is the first thing I tried too...Seems like it is not a current feature unfortunately.

Comment: If a different solution is acceptable: PyCharm flags it.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879640/how-to-configure-pylint-to-check-all-things-pep8-checks), E301 and E303 doesn't seem to be a thing in pylint (yet?).

One alternative would be to use the [pycodestyle](https://github.com/pycqa/pycodestyle) (previously: [pep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8)) tool directly, which would allow you to check for blank lines.

Hopefully you'll like it as much as pylint, despite maybe being a little bit less configurable.