# pep8 not working in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pep8

I want to be alerted when I write python code that violates pep8 in the eclipse editor. As far as I can see, the settings show it should be running pep8. (Below is a screenshot of my pydev settings). I have tried:

- verifying that it is pointing to the correct location for pep8.py
- changing between error and warning
- checking and unchecking 'Redirect pep8 output to console'

[image]

Any suggestions or input on how I can get pep8 to work for me in eclipse, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried the 'redirect pep8 output to console' option?

Comment: Have you looked in the Eclipse log for possible error messages?

Comment: Yes, I have checked and unchecked the "redirect..." and I have checked the eclipse error log.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to actively run pep8 tests when you are ready - not sure where it is hidden in the menus or if there is a keyboard short cut - try looking under 'Tools' in the menus.

The other possibility is that you may not have pep8 correctly installed where it is indicated - try copying the path from the above into a command prompt and seeing if it runs with a sample .py file and does not error.  If it doesn't you should be able to install the pep8 checker from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) under your current python installation and then point eclipse to it.

Comment: pep8 checking runs fine in my environment using the exact same setup as the OP showed with no additional commands. I use it without problems on both Python2 and Python3. Seems likely to me that there is some environmental problem in OP's environment.

Answer (score 0):

Check that "Do code analysis" under Options is checked.

[image: Options]

Answer (score 0):

Per an [answer by Fabio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31001619/832230), in the project's properties, add the package folder to `PYTHONPATH`, and also restart Eclipse if it still doesn't work.

You can also use the latest version of `pep8` as an `External Tool` in Eclipse. For details, see an [answer by Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2296249/832230).